# Reading csv file with Japanese characters into R

Tags: r, csv, locale, multibyte

I am struggling to have R read in a csv file which has some of its columns in standard English characters, some numerical and some fields in Japanese characters.Here is how the data looks like:

```
category,desc,otherdesc,volume
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,かどや製油　純白ごま油,OIL_OTHERS_SML_ECO,83.0
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,オレインリッチ,OIL_OTHERS_MED,137.0
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,ＴＶキャノーラ油,OIL_CANOLA_OTHERS_LRG,3026.0
```

Keeping the R's language setting as English, the japanese characters are converted into some gibberish. When I change the language setting in R to Japanese, `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "japanese")`, I see the file is not read in at all. R gives an error saying:

Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at 'ｻcategory'

I have no clue what's wrong with my csv file or the header names. Can you guide me as to how can I go about reading this csv file into R so that everything is displayed just as they do in the csv file?

Thanks!
Vish

Comment: did you try `read.csv` with `check.names=FALSE`?

Comment: Does this: `df <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ',', text = 'category,desc,otherdesc,volume
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,かどや製油　純白ごま油,OIL_OTHERS_SML_ECO,83.0
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,オレインリッチ,OIL_OTHERS_MED,137.0
UPC - 31401 Age Itameabura,ＴＶキャノーラ油,OIL_CANOLA_OTHERS_LRG,3026.0 ')` work for you? Can you provide a sample csv file? Looks like an encoding issue...

Comment: Fiddle with the `fileEncoding` argument to the read.* functions.

Comment: Maybe a platform issue as well. I just copied your file, save it as a`.csv` using VIM. It reads just fine with `read.table(file.choose(), sep=",", header=TRUE)` without any problem on Mac OS 10.5.8.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: Tried with that option, doesn't work! (u<-read.csv(file.choose(), sep=",", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE).I am using Windows. Could this be platform-dependent? Also, did you need to change the Locale to Japanese?

Comment: This worked for me: read.csv(file.choose(), sep=",", header=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8")
Thank you everybody for your quick help!

Comment: @user2895779 yeah, I did change the locale.

Answer (score 2):

For japanese the below works for me:

df <- read.csv("your_file.csv", fileEncoding="cp932")