# Difficulty reading in text file with Japanese characters into R

Tags: r

I have a tab delimited txt file with the following:

```
1588888 北海道滝川市  ホッカイドウタキカワシ 1
9489884 北海道滝川市二の坂町  ホッカイドウタキカワシニノサカチョウ  1
```

and I'm trying to read it into R with:

```
df <- read.table(file="jap_text.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t", fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

and I'm getting the error message below:

```
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = "jap_text.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\t",  :
   invalid input found on input connection 'jap_text.txt'
2: In read.table(file = "jap_text.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "\t",  :
   incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'jap_text.txt'
```

and when i run:

```
head(df)
```

I'm getting a weird output:

```
       V1 V2
1 1588888 NA
```

How to i address this reading issue in R?

Comment: what about using `read.csv`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading csv file with Japanese characters into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455957/reading-csv-file-with-japanese-characters-into-r)

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue.  Are you sure the file is UTF-8?  What do you get if you use `readLines("jap_text.txt")`?  If you're on Windows, you may need to use the development version of R which has much better UTF-8 support.